# How do I delete an exported environment variable?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, unset

Before installing [gnuplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot), I set the environment variable `GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR = /home/gnuplot/build/src`. During the installation, something went wrong.

I want to remove the `GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR` environment variable. How can I achieve it?

Comment: For those looking for how to do this in Fish shell see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703860/how-do-i-unset-a-variable-in-the-fish-shell (even though this question isn't for a specific shell)

Answer (score 3719, accepted):

`unset` is the command you're looking for.

```bash
unset GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR
```

Comment: but this only works for a session, what about unsetting it definitely? or maybe searching where is the variable set, so you can go and delete it?

Comment: This should work per terminal instance. Generally, each time a terminal window is opened, it will load up variables from various places such as ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, etc. Any variables you set in one terminal instance will not carry over to another. If you have a variable which seems to be set automatically every time you open terminal, try looking through the various hidden files in your home directory for it. Or, to see where it is being set, try "grep -r <X> ~" where <X> is the name of the variable. This may take a while if you have a lot of files in your home directory.

Comment: This removes the variable from the shell too though. Is the only way to `unexport` to do `T="$MYVAR"; unset MYVAR; MYVAR="$T"; unset T` ?

Comment: @olejorgenb At least in bash, you can say `declare +x MYVAR` to remove the export but keep the value in the current shell.

Comment: @PederKlingenberg `export -n MYWAR` works as well in Bash.

Comment: What's the command to unset it across different terminal sessions?

Comment: @default123 There is no single command to unset it across existing sessions.  It will have to be unset in each session.  You are probably better off finding out which initialization file sets it in the first place and edit that, which will remove it from future sessions.  See other comments and answers for details of that. In my experience, calling `unset` is a very rare thing to need to do.

Answer (score 249):

### **Walkthrough of creating and deleting an environment variable in Bash:**

**Test if the DUALCASE variable exists (empty output):**

```bash
env | grep DUALCASE
```

**It does not, so create the variable and export it:**

```bash
DUALCASE=1
export DUALCASE
```

**Check if it is there:**

```bash
env | grep DUALCASE
```

Output:

> DUALCASE=1

**It is there.  So get rid of it:**

```bash
unset DUALCASE
```

**Check if it's still there (empty output):**

```bash
env | grep DUALCASE
```

The DUALCASE exported environment variable is deleted.

### Extra commands to help clear your local and environment variables:

**Unset all local variables back to default on login:**

```bash
CAN="chuck norris"
set | grep CAN
```

Output:

> CAN='chuck norris'

```bash
env | grep CAN # Empty output

exec bash
set | grep CAN
env | grep CAN # Empty output
```

`exec bash` command cleared all the local variables, but not environment variables.

**Unset all environment variables back to default on login:**

```bash
export DOGE="so wow"
env | grep DOGE
```

Output:

> DOGE=so wow

```bash
env -i bash
env | grep DOGE # Empty output
```

`env -i bash` command cleared all the environment variables to default on login.

Comment: maybe `echo $VARIABLE` is better than `env | grep VARIABLE`, it's lighter as it doesn't need to print all variables and then send its output to another (grep) process.
Plus, `env | VARIABLE` could catch more than one variable that matches the same pattern.
Plus2, `echo $VARIABLE` makes possible to complete variable's name by hitting <Tab> (if it exists, that also may be a hint to what you wanna do).

Comment: 'env | grep VARIABLE' is better than 'echo $VARIABLE' because I can tell it's truly gone

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel, `echo $VARIABLE` doesn't tell you whether the VARIABLE is a shell variable (here called "local variable") or an environment variable, which is the whole point of the walkthrough.

Comment: Note that `env -i bash` seems to be creating a subshell (at least on a Mac) which may have unintended consequences.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel using echo won't show existing variable set to empty string or nul. to your point, though, a proper way to test for variable would be `env | grep -e '^VARNAME='`.

Answer (score 31):

The original question doesn't mention how the variable was set, but:

**In [C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) (csh/tcsh)** there are two ways to set an environment variable:

1. `set x = "something"`
2. `setenv x "something"`

The difference in the behaviour is that variables set with the ***setenv*** command are automatically exported to a subshell while  variables set with ***set*** aren't.

To unset a variable set with ***set***, use

```bash
unset x
```

To unset a variable set with ***setenv***, use

```bash
unsetenv x
```

*Note:* in all the above, I assume that the variable name is 'x'.

Credits:

- *[TCSH / CSH: set vs setenv Command Differences](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-difference-between-set-and-setenv-c-shell-variable/)*
- *[set, unset, setenv, unsetenv, export — Shell Environment Variable Built-in Functions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/solaristm-7-reference/0130200484/0130200484_ch18lev1sec24.html)*

Comment: Great addition about the differences between set / setenv wrt subshells!

Answer (score 20):

On Linux and macOS, you can use the command `unset` to remove an environment variable.

```bash
unset GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR
```

---

##### Remove the variable permanently,

###### In Linux

You can edit your shell profile file, such as `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in the `/etc/profile.d` directory and remove the line that exports the variable.

`.bashrc file:`

```bash
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Then, search for the line export `GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR` and delete it. Then save the file.

###### In Windows

use the `setx` command to delete an environment variable.

```bash
setx GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR ""
```

---

You can find more information about environment variables and how to manage them in the following links:

- Linux: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/
- Windows: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Is there a command that removes it 'permanently'?

Kind of like unset, but works for more than just a single terminal instance?

Comment: default123 Short answer, NO. Read answers from e.g. @Trunk if your goal is to find and remove what ever is setting an environment variable.  Though the first place to look is in your own shell initialization files (e.g. .bashrc, and .bash_profile for bash shell).

Answer (score 18):

This may also work.

```bash
export GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR=
```

Comment: The variable still exists, but it contains an empty string, as you can see in the output of the `env` command. It just might be the case that the application that uses the variable does not distinguish between non-existent and empty environment variable.

Comment: yes it will contain, this was just to remove value not to remove variable. But yes one can use - unset GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR.

Comment: This doesn't work in the case of the PAGER variable.  I tried to unset my PAGER setting with `export PAGER=`, but that just disabled paging entirely--all my man pages just dumped straight to the terminal.  `unset PAGER` did the trick, reverting it to default behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps it is time to [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47904504/edit) your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in the above answers, `unset GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR` should work if you have used `export` to set the variable. If you have set it permanently in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` then simply removing it from there will work.

Answer (score 1):

**LINUX**

First find which script file defines and adds the variable to the environment.

Look in /etc files like profile, bash.bashrc, .bashrc, .bashrc_login, etc

And look in similarly named files in the user's home directory.

If it's not in any of those, it's likely that it's in some script file that was part of an installed package. For example, the package SDKMAN (for managing alternate SDK versions) creates a variable called DERBY_HOME. To find the script file creating it, apply the following search command to the /etc folder:

```
$ sudo egrep -lir THE_VAR_NAME /etc
```

This should produce some output like:

```
/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh
```

The separate file *jdk.csh* is needed for the C-shell environment if users have defaulted to it.

Once found it is simply a matter of navigating to the folder containing the script files, in this case here /etc/profile.d/ and then editing the files (with admin permission), removing the variable assignments and saving:

```
$ cd /etc/profile.d/

$ sudo gedit jdk.sh

$ sudo gedit jdk.sh
```

Of course, in this case the package setting the env variable is in use so I kept it.

But if the package were not in use and the env vars dead weight to the startup process, then it should be deleted.

**WINDOWS**

Use the process shown in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rS6o6rSR0U).