# Unset an environment variable for a single command

Tags: bash, unix, environment-variables

In Bash, we can set an environment variable for a single command this way:

```
FOO=bar somecommand
```

What if we want to *unset* a variable for a single command?

Comment: Related not just single command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877727/how-do-i-delete-an-exported-environment-variable

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Technically, they're not environment variables until someone `export`s them.  But you can at least set them to empty:

```
FOO= some command
```

If removing them from the environment is enough, you can use `env`:

```
env -u FOO somecommand
```

Comment: You can also use a subshell: `(unset FOO; some command)`. But anyway, I consider empty environment variables to be different from absent environment variables, so I wouldn't use the `FOO= some command` approach.

Comment: (So do I). (OHAI cky, it's been a long time!)

Comment: Technically they are environment variables, just not for the current environment: [the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion)

Comment: @glennjackman No, what JB is saying is that running `FOO=bar` by itself does not set an environment variable, unless `FOO` is exported.

Comment: I just glanced at the bash doc again and it actually uses the term environment for the shell's local variables as well. But for the non-exported ones I'd consider that an implementation detail indeed. I'm not going to check whether it calls `setenv` just this evening.

Comment: @JB: it doesn't call setenv for exported variables either, but it does add them to the list of environment variables passed to child processes. Since bash doesn't really distinguish between environment variables and other types of variables, the result of `export` isn't particularly visible in the shell in which is was performed. (Of course, you can see the difference with `declare -p`.) Regardless of how you feel about empty and absent variables, bash doesn't really distinguish between them either, unless you `set -u` -- and if you do, a lot of standard scripts will break.

Comment: Setting the variable to be empty worked for my purpose (although I wasn't expecting it to). Thanks!

Comment: @rici, as a `command` there might be a `make` which differs which environment variables are unset and which are simply empty.

Comment: @JB., for that specific command `FOO` will be set as an environment variable

Answer (score 24):

```
env -u FOO somecommand
```

This will remove the environment variable `FOO` from the `somecommand` process' environment.

And to unset multiple variables:

```
env -u FOO -u FOO2 somecommand
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone intending to run a command with none of their environment variables, you can do so by running:

```sh
env -i somecommand
```

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky when "`somecommand`" is a *shell function*.

One-shot environment variable assignments, such as '`FOO`' in "`FOO=bar cmd`", exist only during the invocation of '`cmd`'.
However, if '`cmd`' happens to be a shell function, then '`FOO`' is assigned in the executing shell itself, and that assignment remains until the process exits (unless explicitly unset).
Since this side-effect of "`FOO=bar shell_func`" is unlikely to be intentional, it should be avoided.

To further illustrates how the `FOO= aCommand` is dangerous, consider Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), which avoids "FOO= `shell_function` (unsetting `FOO` just for one command).

See [commit d6509da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6509da620feb774dce6de9fe71d38fef9f07c88), [commit a7fbf12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7fbf12f2f31cb5aefb4fe7f467564be32c62968), [commit c7973f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7973f249ebe86f10ec4b420a8ab83b8b83bce22) (26 Dec 2019) by [Jonathan Nieder (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c7372c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7372c9e2c11fa0adbfef2b9c5e5ba4ce19eb688), 30 Jan 2020)</sup>

> ### [`fetch test`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7973f249ebe86f10ec4b420a8ab83b8b83bce22): avoid use of "VAR= cmd" with a shell function
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>
>
> Just like assigning a nonempty value, **assigning an empty value to a shell variable when calling a function produces non-portable behavior**: in some shells, the assignment lasts for the duration of the function invocation, and in others, it persists after the function returns.
>
> **Use an explicit subshell with the `envvar` exported to make the behavior consistent across shells and crystal clear**.
>
> All previous instances of this pattern used "`VAR=value`" (with nonempty `value`), which is already diagnosed automatically by "make test-lint" since [a0a630192d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a0a630192dca77794b2ea94aeb2e6dff0cc1810b) (t/check-non-portable-shell: detect "`FOO=bar shell_func`", 2018-07-13).

For example, instead of:

```
GIT_TEST_PROTOCOL_VERSION= trace_fetch client origin to_fetch
```

Use a subshell:

```
(
    GIT_TEST_PROTOCOL_VERSION= &&
    export GIT_TEST_PROTOCOL_VERSION &&
    trace_fetch client origin to_fetch
) &&
...
```