# Git error "fatal: GIT_WORK_TREE (or --work-tree=<directory>) not allowed without specifying GIT_DIR (or --git-dir=<directory>)"

Tags: git, environment-variables, git-config, git-init

I have `GIT_WORK_TREE` set to `.` and `GIT_DIR` set to `.git`. When I run `git init --bare`, I get the following error:

> fatal: `GIT_WORK_TREE` (or `--work-tree=<directory>`) not allowed without specifying `GIT_DIR` (or `--git-dir=<directory>`)

What's up with that? I suspect that it might have something to do with `GIT_DIR` being set to `.` (maybe it considers `GIT_DIR` unset if it points to the current working directory?). Regardless, it would be great to have this behave properly so I don't have to unset GIT_WORK_TREE every time I want to initialize a Git repo.

Comment: [Details of our chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/conversation/chat-with-synful), for future reference.

Answer (score 10):

This error message comes from [`builtin/init-db.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/efc8a625e9b03e6f8ceed37ccd4b9167a7447e31/builtin/init-db.c#L564-L574)

```
    /*
     * GIT_WORK_TREE makes sense only in conjunction with GIT_DIR
     * without --bare.  Catch the error early.
     */
    git_dir = getenv(GIT_DIR_ENVIRONMENT);
    work_tree = getenv(GIT_WORK_TREE_ENVIRONMENT);
    if ((!git_dir || is_bare_repository_cfg == 1) && work_tree)
        die(_("%s (or --work-tree=<directory>) not allowed without "
              "specifying %s (or --git-dir=<directory>)"),
```

So on Unbuntu, unset `GIT_WORK_TREE` just before doing a `git init --bare`.
See "[Unset an environmental variable for a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18906391/6309)":

```
env -u GIT_WORK_TREE git init --bare
# or
GIT_WORK_TREE=  git init --bare
```

> I'm adding remote on windows perfectly

`git init --bare` is not "adding remote", so you need to check what command triggers that error message.

---

On Windows, use [`cmd /V/ /C` as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31824572/6309):

```
cmd /V /C "set "GIT_WORK_TREE=" && git init --bare"
```

Comment: what would be the answer for Windows ?

Comment: @irvnriir I have edited the answer to add the Windows syntax.