# How to start a program with bash -c, redirect / disable GUI of that app

Tags: bash, go

Currently I'm starting a java application with

```
bash -c java -jar app.jar -config config.json
```

The app opens a window, displaying some output and closes. The output is also available on stdout, so I don't need (want) the GUI to display.

How can I prevent bash to forward the X output?

**Follow up:**

I'm running this in a go application, so based on el.pescado's answer, I have implemented this as:

```golang
func runcmd(cmd string, workdir string) ([]byte, error) {
  ex := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd)
  ex.Env = []string{"DISPLAY= "}
  ex.Dir = workdir
  return ex.Output()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1. First, you should check if that application can run without GUI (often called "headless" mode)
2. You can [unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906350/unset-an-environment-variable-for-a-single-command) `DISPLAY` variable, so that your app won't find your X11 server - but keep in mind that application might not work without X server

eg.

```
DISPLAY= bash -c java -jar app.jar -config config.json # note space after '='
# or
env -u DISPLAY bash -c java -jar app.jar -config config.json
```

3. You could use in-memory virtual X server such as [xfvb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) and point your application to display its windows there.

eg.

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x32
DISPLAY=:1 bash -c java -jar app.jar -config config.json
```

Comment: @mgagnon #2 `DISPLAY= bash -c java -jar app.jar -config config.json`