# How do I unset a variable in the fish shell?

Tags: fish

In bash I can unset a variable with

```
unset myvar
```

In fish I get

```
fish: Unknown command 'unset'
```

What's the equivalent for unset in fish.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Fish uses options on the `set` command to manipulate shell variables.

Unset a variable with the `-e` or `--erase` option.

```
set -e myvar
```

Additionally you can define a function

```
function unset
  set --erase $argv
end

funcsave unset
```

or an abbreviation

```
abbr --add unset 'set --erase'
```

or an alias in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

```
alias unset 'set --erase'
```

Comment: Note that the function will not be able to erase local variables because it starts a new variable scope. Add `--no-scope-shadowing` to the function definition to fix this.

Comment: Added an abbreviation method and a `funcsave` so the `unset` function sticks around.