# Disable SLS_DEBUG=* in the Serverless Framework

Tags: macos, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-architecture, aws-serverless

When using the serverless framework (on a Mac OS X High Sierra), the `SLS_DEBUG` environmental variable was set to enable verbose debug info

```
export SLS_DEBUG=*
```

**Question:** Now how do you disable it (other than moving to a new terminal)? `export SLS_DEBUG=false` did not do the trick.

Comment: You can do it as any other environment variable. Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877727/how-do-i-delete-an-exported-environment-variable

Answer (score 21):

You can remove an environment variable by:

```
unset SLS_DEBUG
```

Comment: How do you remove SLS_DEBUG in windows ? I deleted my enviornment variable but it still gives me all the logs

Comment: @ashakshan did you try https://www.digitalcitizen.life/remove-edit-clear-environment-variables/