# What is the helper refering to when it says "For each NAME"?

Tags: linux, bash

I was looking at how to unset an exported variable en bash and came accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877727/how-do-i-delete-an-exported-environment-variable).

An answer contains the `unset` command. Doing a little `unset --help` to check what's available and its description.

```
$ unset --help
unset: unset [-f] [-v] [-n] [name ...]
    Unset values and attributes of shell variables and functions.

    For each NAME, remove the corresponding variable or function.
```

What is a NAME in "For each NAME" ? What is it refering to ?

Comment: It's the `name` arguments to the command: `[name ...]`

Comment: Those are the names of the variables and functions you want to unset.

Comment: The mixing of lowercase and uppercase is very unfortunate.

Comment: @Barmar Hooo. Ok. I though it was something else. As Roadowl, the mixing of lower and uppercase confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the `name` parameters in the syntax line. So they're the names of the variables that are being unset.

It uses uppercase to highlight the word in the sentence, similar to the way man pages use fonts or inverse coloring to highlight keywords.