# Setting exception breakpoint for "warning"

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I debug a project and I get a scary warning somewhere in it:

```
../opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:26: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce
  return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
```

Pycharm allows to stop at a exception through setting exception breakpoint, as document [says](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2021.1/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-properties). I tried and it didn't work for **warning** (I assume warning is not Exception)!

Is there a way for me to stop when this warning raises and see what's going on?

Comment: you can turn warnings into errors by setting `PYTHONWARNINGS=error` (environment variable) or `-W error` on the commandline (if you have access to that)

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnthonySottile . And how can I revert it back?! If I couldn't resolve it I don't want to be hindered by it!

I think I found the solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877727/how-do-i-delete-an-exported-environment-variable]. Thanks!

Comment: undo whatever you did?