# CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG default value?

Tags: pytorch, lstm

I am currently working with **PyTorch** (more precisely with LSTMs using CUDA) on `Ubuntu 18.04`. As mentioned [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html),  I have set `CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG=:4096:2`.

However, if I train my `LSTM` using the same hyperparameters as before its performance decreases a lot. So I would like to reset the setting. Does anyone know the default value or how I could possibly obtain the settings I used before?

Answer (score 0):

I think to rest the environment variable you just need to unset the variable

simply in your terminal write

```
unset CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG
```

for more info:
[How do I delete an exported environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877727/how-do-i-delete-an-exported-environment-variable)