# Disabling python's assert() without -0 flag

Tags: python, debugging, assert

I'm running a python script from inside a different software (it provides a python interface to manipulate its data structures).

I'm optimizing my code for speed and would like to see what impact on performance my asserts have.

I'm unable to use `python -O`. What other options do I have, to programatically disable all asserts in python code? The variable `__debug__` (which is cleared by `-O` flag) cannot be assigned to :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The docs say](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement),

> The value for the built-in variable [`__debug__`] is determined when the
>   interpreter starts.

So, if you can not control how the python interpreter is started, then it looks like you can not disable assert.

Here then are some other options:

1. The safest way is to manually remove all the assert statements.
2. If all your assert statements occur on lines by themselves, then
   perhaps you could remove them with

   ```
   sed -i 's/assert /pass #assert /g' script.py
   ```

   Note that this will mangle your code if other code comes after the assert. For example, the sed command above would comment-out the `return` in a line like this:

   ```
   assert x; return True
   ```

   which would change the logic of your program.

   If you have code like this, it would probably be best to manually remove the asserts.
3. There might be a way to remove them programmatically by parsing your
   script with the `tokenize` module, but writing such a program to
   remove asserts may take more time than it would take to manually
   remove the asserts, especially if this is a one-time job.
4. If the other piece of software accepts .pyc files, then there is a
   dirty trick which seems to work on my machine, though note [a Python
   core developer warns against this](http://bugs.python.org/issue12982) (See Éric Araujo's comment on 2011-09-17). Suppose your script is called `script.py`.

   - Make a temporary script called, say, temp.py:

     ```
     import script
     ```
   - Run `python -O temp.py`. This creates `script.pyo`.
   - Move `script.py` and `script.pyc` (if it exists) out of your PYTHONPATH
     or whatever directory the other software is reading to find your
     script.
   - Rename `script.pyo` --> `script.pyc`.

   Now when the other software tries to import your script, it will
   only find the `pyc` file, which has the asserts removed.

   For example, if `script.py` looks like this:

   ```
   assert False
   print('Got here')
   ```

   then running `python temp.py` will now print `Got here` instead of raising an AssertionError.

Comment: small fix: 's/assert/pass #assert/g. Otherwise `if` branches with only one `assert` statement will fail to compile :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this with an environment variable, as described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668496/320036). Setting [`PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE) is equivalent to starting Python with the `-O` option. As an example, this works in [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) 2.78, which embeds Python 3.5:

```
blender --python-expr 'assert False; print("foo")'

PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1 blender --python-expr 'assert False; print("foo")'
```

The first command prints a traceback, while the second just prints "foo".

Answer (score 0):

As @unutbu describes, there is no official way of doing this.  However, a simple strategy is to define a flag like `_test` somewhere (for example, as keyword argument to a function, or as a global variable in a module), then include this in your assert statements as follows:

```
def f(x, _test=True):
    assert not _test or x > 0
    ...
```

Then you can disable asserts in that function if needed.

```
f(x, _test=False)
```