# Keeping assert despite the -O (optimize) flag

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter, assert

I place many checks of the program state, whose failure would indicate a bug in the code. In such cases, I'd love to use `assert condition` simply because it reads nicer than `if not condition: raise MyException`.

Using `assert` instead of `raise` has two problems.

1. `assert` does not allow to specify the exception to be raised, so catching it later becomes hard (catching `AssertionError` may catch too much).
2. `assert` is disabled when -O flag is passed to the interpreter.

In my environment any bug in the code requires that I discard any results until the bug is identified and fixed. Therefore, there's no point catching exceptions raised by the above checks. Thus, problem #1 is irrelevant in my situation.

Problem #2 is serious. I want my checks to remain in production code, since correctness is far more important than performance in my environment. Few people use -O flag today; but one day I or someone else may prefer to use it (e.g., to suppress code behind `if __debug__`, or because -O might actually optimize code in the future). Since all my `assert` statements must remain active in the production code, I'll need to replace all `assert` statements with something else. Is there any way to force `assert` to stay despite the -O flag?

By the way, I'm planning to customize the behavior of `assert` by printing variable values from the line that caused the assert to fail. I think I can do it by replacing `sys.excepthook` with my own function that catches `AssertionError`, reads the traceback, finds the relevant source code, prints the variables from the relevant line, and then reraises the exception. If anyone sees a problem with that, please let me know.

Comment: I assume you're using `assert` to identify catastrophic failure conditions, and not just ordinary exception conditions?

Comment: Precisely. I'm still using proper exceptions to catch unusual inputs, etc - I'm only using `assert` to catch mistakes in the code. In my particular environment, any mistake in the code is considered a catastrophic failure (production code is not allowed to run if it contains any known bugs, however minor).

Comment: It doesn't look good. Removing assertions is apparently a "feature" of the -O switch. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1273211/102937

Comment: I updated the question to emphasize that I'm not concerned with the future behavior of the -O flag. I'm just concerned with the possibility that anyone (today or in the future) may want to use `-O` for whatever reason. If so, they'll break the intended behavior of the code (specifically, error checking).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am afraid you are right :( However, there might be a reasonably reliable safe monkey patch that would protect `assert` statements somehow. Even if it simply exits if the interpreter is called with -O flag, and warns the user, I'd live with that.. not ideal, of course..

Comment: Assuming that your environment is configuration-controlled in some way (a reasonable assumption, given the critical nature of your code), couldn't you just require your users to refrain from using the -O switch, or provide a stub executable that calls the Python interpreter without the -O switch?

Comment: Each user runs the code themselves, but it's a good suggestion to provide some configuration wrapper around the way they call the interpreter.

Comment: Just don't use assertions if they aren't what you need. Be explicit, the `assert` statement carries those "I may or may not be run at all" semantics. If you just want to save typing on error conditions, create a function `def require(cond, msg): if not cond: raise MyException(msg)`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey @delnan: Thanks, I'm persuaded that I've been trying to use `assert` differently than what the language intended it to.. I'll use something like `require` instead for my purposes. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @Delnan can write an answer. Can't you Delnan? :) I think this question has value for future readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just don't use assertions if they aren't what you need. Instead be explicit that you'll throw this exception if some condition is violated. The assert statement always carries a "I may or may not be run at all" side. It's less hacky, less astonishing, less likely to break in the future, and does not require you to prevent users from adding `-O`.

If you just want to save typing, you can do so. Create a function like this (a more specific name is highly recommended) and use it instead of `assert`:

```
def require(cond, msg):
    if not cond:
        raise MyException(msg)
```