# Enabling/disabling assert statements in python using code

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert, assertion

In C/C++, a programmer can easily enable/disable assert statements with macros in the source code. Can this be done in a similar way in python?

I know assertions can be disabled using the -O flag (capital O) in python. However, I prefer to do this in the source code.

I am using python 3.7.3 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no comparable way to achieve this in Python. The `-O` flag sets the built-in variable `__debug__` to `False`, but Python does not allow for changing it at run-time.

One possible solution would be to encapsulate your assertions in if-statements, using a global variable to control whether `assert` statements get executed or not, but I doubt this is the answer you're looking for.

For more information about the topic, you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273211/disable-assertions-in-python/21325317) answer to a related question.