# python console scripts setup in setuptools: how to disable asserts

Tags: python, setuptools, assert

These lines in setup.cfg setup leads to the creation of a script `mydemo` that will execute the run function of the module `__main__`:

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    mydemo = mypackage.__main__:run
```

I would like `mydemo` to execute `run` with disabled asserts. Is there a way of doing this ?

Comment: `python -O` is the only way to disable asserts. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56078190/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+disable+asserts

Comment: @phd you may be correct, but I find it strange: in practice, this makes assert almost unusable for packaged python software.

Comment: @phd and also, ```python -0``` could be called by the ```mydemo``` script generated by the setuptools. I would not be crazy to imagine that this has been thought of.

Comment: That explains why `assert`s have so little usage. BTW it's letter `O` (from the word "optimize"), not digit `0`.