# Use subclasses of abstract outer class in nested class

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic, abstract-base-class

I want to use all subclasses of an abstract class in the nested config class of a pydantic class like this:

```
def custom_json_loads(classes, ....):
    ##use classes here for json parsing

class Outer(BaseModel, abc.ABC):
    name = "test"
    class Config:
        json_loads = partial(custom_json_loads, Outer.__subclasses__)
```

The aim of it all is that I know the OuterClass Type for my JSON and the name of the classes signify which instance of a subclass should be created

E.g. I have BlueOuter, RedOuter, GreenOuter and in  the json there would be
"outer" : {
"name" : "BlueOuter",
....}

But I don't want to import all possible variants of the subclasses because they evolve over time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a [discriminated union](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions)?

```python
import abc
from typing import Annotated, Literal, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Outer(BaseModel, abc.ABC):
    ...


class BlueOuter(Outer):
    name: Literal["BlueOuter"]


class RedOuter(Outer):
    name: Literal["RedOuter"]


class GreenOuter(Outer):
    name: Literal["GreenOuter"]


OuterUnion = Annotated[
    Union[BlueOuter, RedOuter, GreenOuter], Field(discriminator="name")
]


class Foo(BaseModel):
    outer: OuterUnion


print(Foo.parse_raw('{"outer": {"name": "BlueOuter"}}'))
print(Foo.parse_raw('{"outer": {"name": "RedOuter"}}'))
print(Foo.parse_raw('{"outer": {"name": "GreenOuter"}}'))
```

Output:

```
outer=BlueOuter(name='BlueOuter')
outer=RedOuter(name='RedOuter')
outer=GreenOuter(name='GreenOuter')
```

If you worry about the need to mantain `OuterUnion` when a new `Outer` subclass is added, you could have a unit test to check that `OuterUnion` has all the subclasses of `Outer`:

```python
class OrangeOuter(Outer):
    name: Literal["OrangeOuter"]


outer_union_classes = OuterUnion.__args__[0].__args__
for subclass in Outer.__subclasses__():
    assert (
        subclass in outer_union_classes
    ), f"{subclass.__name__} must be a member of OuterUnion (classes: {[c.__name__ for c in outer_union_classes]}). Please add it."
```

Output:

```
AssertionError: OrangeOuter must be a member of OuterUnion (classes: ['BlueOuter', 'RedOuter', 'GreenOuter']). Please add it.
```

Comment: Wow, that really looks nice. I thought about discriminated unions but wasn't happy that I couldn't automatically add all options. Thanks for the unit test idea!

Comment: I got a problem with the subclasses though: If I accidently don't import all subclasses, I will never be notified of a missing one. The classes are spread all over the place

Comment: @Tabea, I think the easiest solution would be to adopt a convention about where to place the subclasses. Now, if you **really** need a stronger check, maybe an option could be using an `assert` in an [__init_subclass__()](https://peps.python.org/pep-0487/) method of `Outer` to check that every subclass is a member of `OuterUnion`. Trying to use a subclass that is not a member of `OuterUnion` should give an `AssertionError` at runtime. Note that assertions can be disabled as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668496/2738151).